# TopologicalError: The operation 'GEOSDifference_r' could not be performed

Tags: python-3.x, topology, osmnx

I'm trying some code to get the building footprints of Barcelona:

```
import osmnx as ox
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline

place_name = "Barcelona, Barcelona, Catalonia, Spain"
graph = ox.graph_from_place(place_name)
buildings = ox.footprints_from_place(place_name)
```

When I run the code it yields the following error message:

```
TopologicalError: The operation 'GEOSDifference_r' could not be performed. Likely cause is invalidity of the geometry <shapely.geometry.polygon.Polygon object at 0x00000262079B6550>
```

I've tried updating the OSMnx version but it seems not to be the problem.
How can I solve this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is posted in the following github repository:

https://github.com/gboeing/osmnx/blob/5176d4a2f86fd2adaf523d3d9bd0bed9b9b1d6ec/osmnx/footprints.py

You should change the `footprints.py` file with the updated code.
To do so you can:
-open the file in the osmnx package paste, delete its contents and copy the updated ones,

-or create a new file and then replace it in the osmnx package paste.